# My .sh script Syntax Error: Unexpected End of File

Tags: javascript, bash, shell, syntax

When i run my .sh script i get **syntax error: unexpected end of file**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Make sure the port is not already bound
if ss -lnt | grep -q :"$SERVER_PORT"; then
  echo "Another process is already listening to port $SERVER_PORT"
  exit 1;
fi

RETRY_INTERVAL=${RETRY_INTERVAL:-0.2}

if ! systemctl is-active --quiet elasticsearch.service; then
  sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service
  # Wait until Elasticsearch is ready to respond
  until curl --silent "$ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTNAME":"$ELASTICSEARCH_PORT" -w "" -o /dev/null; do
    sleep "$RETRY_INTERVAL"
  done
fi

# Run our API server as a background process
npm run serve &

until ss -lnt | grep -q :"$SERVER_PORT"; do
  sleep "$RETRY_INTERVAL"
done

npx cucumber-js spec/cucumber/features --require-module @babel/register --require spec/cucumber/steps

kill -15 0
```

actual result when i run my script is syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: I ran your script against shellcheck.net and didn't find any issue.

Please make sure your script is saved using LF new lines.

Comment: Remove lines/blocks until you have a minimal block of code with your problem.